# What is the lifespan of player-placed Geotags?

Tags: ssx-2012

In the 2012 version of *SSX*, what is the lifespan of a player-placed Geotag? Do the lifespans of the Geotag depend on their value/color (green, purple, gold, red)?

The description indicates there is a maximum value of credits earned and there are badges related to placing certain numbers of Geotags that are abandoned, but I have yet to find where it says how long a Geotag lasts, nor have I been successful in placing any that have not been collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifespan of all Geotags is exactly 24 hours.

For more information, read: [EA Forums|Geotags: Explained In Detail](https://web.archive.org/web/20130307155722/http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/8274470.page)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but we will appreciate if you summarize it or  quote a small excerpt or two here, to make this answer a little more substantial than just one link.